# Entity Framework migration consisting only of SQL() calls?

Tags: entity-framework

We'd like to create an Entity Framework migration that solely runs a pre-defined SQL query:

```
public partial class MySqlMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        SQL(...up sql...);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        SQL(...down sql...);
    }
}
```

When we try to run the migration, EF skips it and tells us that there are no explicit migrations pending. For some reason I was under the impression that this sort of thing is possible -- am I crazy or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I do this all the time. It should be working. Here are some tips: http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check! We'll review our assumptions today and figure out what's up.